# Change x-axis label in asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I'm using asymptote to make a heatmap. I have a array of values with two entries, these entries go from 0 to 50, but both represent physical quantities from 0 to 1.

I would like to have an x-axis and a y-axis which go all the way from 0 to 50 but with the label which goes from 0 to 1, does anyone know how to do this ?

I include my code so far :

```
import graph;
import palette;
import patterns;

file in=input("input.dat").line();
real[][] vals = in;

pen outside = lightgrey;

pen[] Palette = Gradient(100, white, blue);

xaxis("$x$",YZero,
  xmin=-1,
  RightTicks(Label("$%.2g$"),
             new real[]{1,20,40,60}),
  above=false); 
yaxis("$y$",ymin = -1);

image(vals,Range(minValue,maxValue),(mx,my),(Mx,My),Palette);
```

Thanks for the help !

Slvn

Comment: `RightTicks(Label("$%.2g$"), new real[] 0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1})` gives labels from 0 to 1.

Comment: It does not give me what I would like...

Let's say that I have an array A, indexed by 0, 1, 2, 3,..., 9 and I want to plot A[0], A[1],... but on the x axis I don't want the label 0, 1,... but for instance 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 instead... 
I'm sorry if I'm not very clear

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, you can modify the `x-axis` label by defining `ticklabel`. Following the documentation (and examples) and the graph.asy file

```
typedef string ticklabel(real);

ticklabel Format(string s=defaultformat)
{
return new string(real x) {return format(s,x);};
}
ticklabel DefaultFormat=Format();
```

`ticklabel` returns from `x` real a string. I modified the documentation example.

```
    import graph;
    import palette;

    size(10cm,10cm,IgnoreAspect);

    real f(real x, real y) {
      return 0.9*pow10(2*sin(x/5+2*y^0.25)) + 0.1*(1+cos(10*log(y)));
    }

    scale(Linear,Log,Log);

    pen[] Palette=BWRainbow();

    bounds range=image(f,Automatic,(0,1),(100,100),nx=200,Palette);

    string mod(real x)
    {
    return format(x/10,locale="en_US.utf8");
    }

    ticklabel mytick()
    {
    return new string(real x)
    {
    return  mod(x);
    };
    }

    ticklabel mytick=mytick();

    xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,RightTicks(mytick,
          new real[]{1,20,40,60,70,95}),
         above=true); 

    yaxis("$y$",LeftRight,RightTicks,above=true);

    palette("$f(x,y)$",range,(0,200),(100,250),Top,Palette,
            PaletteTicks(ptick=linewidth(0.5*linewidth())));
```

In fact if you do not need any option in your ticklabel function, the command

```
      xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,RightTicks(ticklabel=mod,
            new real[]{1,20,40,60,70,95}),
            above=true);
```

gives a similar result. Without specifying `new real[]{1,20,40,60,70,95})` you have 10 to 100 transformed by 1 to 10...

[image]

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for, once again thanks @O.G. !